# Input Box Names: Why name it with a [ ]?

Tags: html, asp-classic

As I'm still trying to resolve my other issue (need some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007953/jquery-selectors-can-i-use-class-for-select-lists)!), I'm exploring on how to name form elements which are the same, but on different rows.

Following this example [here](http://eftakhairul.com/dynamically-add-and-delete-html-table-row-on-user-click-using-jquery/), the author of the article named his textboxes to be "input_box_one". The jQuery function he has written also duplicates the input boxes to have the same name. I would like to know the reason for naming his textboxes like that, and how does the server script he is going to write collect the input from textboxes which are similarly named?

I'm going to be writing in Classic ASP.

```
<table id = "options-table">                    
    <tr>
        <td>Input-Box-One</td>
        <td>Input-Box-Two</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type = "text"    name = "input_box_one[]" /></td>
        <td><input type = "text"    name = "input_box_two[]" /></td>
        <td><input type = "button" class = "del" value = "Delete" /></td>
    </tr>                  

    <tr>
        <td><input type = "text"    name = "input_box_one[]" /></td>
        <td><input type = "text"    name = "input_box_two[]" /></td>
        <td><input type = "button" class = "add" value = "Add More" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ASP Classic the `Request.Form("someName")` returns an object that implements the `IStringList` interface.  This interface has two members `Item([i]])` which is the default property and `Count`.

You should remove the [] suffixes if you are posting to ASP.  You can access multiple values that use the same name using the additional indexer parameter `i`.  E.g.

```
 Dim someValue :  someValue = Request.Form("someName")(2)
```

I can't remember if this collection is 0 or 1 based but should be easy for you to test.  The object may also support `For Each` as well but that may not be that useful in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers!  I believe you are talking to something similar as [this](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_form2)?

Comment: @kosherjellyfish: Yes I'm describing the inner workings of ASP that makes that w3schools example work.

Comment: @kosher please mark this answer as accepted by ticking the green V icon to the left if it solved your issue.

Comment: A collection in Classic ASP (especially in this case), is 1-based. Meaning, the first iteration of the collection is 1 (not 0)... FYI

Answer (score 4):

`[]` is a PHPism. It causes the PHP form parser to represent data in `$_POST['fieldname']` or `$_GET['fieldname']` as an array.

PHP is the only language I know where the standard HTML form data parser requires special names in the data to switch between scalar and array mode.

Comment: Wonder how long we could keep a "PHP is the only language I know where..." thread going...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple input fields with the same name will be presented as comma separated values under the input `name` attribute in Classic ASP.

So,

```
<input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" value="foo" />
<input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" value="bar" />
```

in a `form` after a submit in classic ASP, `request.form("input_box_one[]")`

would give you:

`"foo,bar"`

Comment: They won't be submitted like that, it is (presumably) how ASP will treat them. What will it do if the data includes a comma? (I think this might actually be a worse way to handle things then PHP does, I'm shocked).

Comment: my bad, you're right. I recall ASP puking all over itself when the data had commas in it. So you have to do some client side validation to escape commas. And after that you wish for good luck!

Comment: Browsers will escape the commas included in data entered in inputs.  If you are composing your own entity body for posting then you need to correctly escape characters like , &  and = as a browser would.